# How to use Relationship in Email template in salesforce

Tags: email, email-template

Two objects have Master Detail relationship `Milestone -> contract` object and another two objects have lookup relationship `Contract-> Account`, Now i am in Milestone object, i want to fetch the account name from Milestone object using Email template for subject in salesforce

Milestone is the Custom object for Contract object

I have tried this Relationship:

```
{!Milestone__c.Contracts.Account}
```

to access account name in emai template subject in salesforce? but not working ? anyone please help me for this relationship answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Give the Relationship Value - `{!Account.Name}` only in Email Template Subject Value

No need of Cross field Relationship Values for `Milestone__c` object